# How to convert milliseconds into a hh:mm:ss.sss timestamp format in R

Tags: r, datetime

Although there seem to be numerous posts concerned with this issue or related issues, I could not find a post providing a solution *in R*.
The problem should be easy to solve once you know how to do it: I have vectors with milliseconds. I'd like to mutate them into hours, minutes, seconds (with three decimals). For example:

```
x <- c(29, 300, 1000, 213451)
```

The expected result is this:

```
# "00:00:00.029"  "00:00:00.300"  "00:00:01.000"  "00:03:33.451"
```

What I've tried so far is this convoluted series of operations:

```
hrs = x / (60 * 60 * 1000)
mins = (hrs %% 1) * 60
secs <- sprintf(((mins %% 1) * 60), fmt = '%#.3f')
paste(trunc(hrs), trunc(mins), secs, sep = ":")
[1] "0:0:0.029"  "0:0:0.300"  "0:0:1.000"  "0:3:33.451"
```

The result is better than nothing but still at a remove from the expected result and, what's more, the code to get there is anything but straightforward or elegant.
What's a quicker and more elegant way to convert milliseconds into the timestamp format?

**EDIT**:
Alternatively, what I've tried is this:

```
library(chron)
times(x / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
```

But this fails to print the decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `"%OSn"` to give the seconds truncated to `n` decimal places, where `n` is between 0 and 6.

```
format(as.POSIXct(x / 1000, "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01"), "%H:%M:%OS3")

# [1] "00:00:00.029" "00:00:00.300" "00:00:01.000" "00:03:33.450"
```